# Python twitter package : get error code

Tags: python, error-handling, python-twitter

I'm not yet very familiar with error handling in Python. I'd like to know how to retrieve the error code when I get an error using the `python-twitter` package :

```
import twitter

#[...]

try:
    twitter_connexion.friendships.create(screen_name = "someone_who_blocked_me", follow = True)
except twitter.TwitterHTTPError as twittererror:
     print(twittererror)
```

> Twitter sent status 403 for URL: 1.1/friendships/create.json using parameters: (follow=True&oauth_consumer_key=XXX&oauth_nonce=XXX&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=XXX&oauth_token=XXX&oauth_version=1.0&screen_name=someone_who_blocked_me&oauth_signature=XXX)
>   details: {'errors': [{'message': 'You have been blocked from following this account at the request of the user.', 'code': 162}]}

In this case, I'd like to retrieve the `'code': 162` part, or just the `162`.

`twittererror.args` is a tuple with one element in it, which is a string, `print(twittererror.args[0][0:10])` outputs `Twitter se`

How can I get the `162` ?

(Obviously, `twittererror.args[0][582:585]` is not the answer I'm looking for, as any other error message will be of a different length and the error code won't be at `[582:585]`)

Comment: What is the output of `print(dir(twittererror))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at how the TwitterHTTPError is defined in [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter/blob/master/twitter/api.py), you should obtain the dict with `twittererror.response_data`.

Therefore you can do something like that:

```
import twitter

#[...]

try:
    twitter_connexion.friendships.create(screen_name = "someone_who_blocked_me", follow = True)
except twitter.TwitterHTTPError as twittererror:
     for error in twittererror.response_data.get("errors", []):
          print(error.get("code", None))
```